# CentOS force password change issue

Tags: linux, security, centos

I wanted to force root user to change password on next login , so I executed command

> `chage -d 0 root`.

The command executed successfully and return code as 0.Even /etc/shadow file is showing changes properly as follow

> root:$1$ZlexRZiM$3cb5GDF9s7.U0l/Xwoh0E1:0:1:90:7:::

Still system is not forcing root user to change password.I even tried to expire password by executing command

> passwd -e root

still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

IT is a very strange behavior, this should work since it is a rather standard way to do it.

What I would check is:

- Full logout, don't test it with the "sudo -i" or "sudo su" to test it and perform a clean login as root (straight as root)
- Check the /etc/login.defs file for variables settings (even if I don't think it is much probable). Variables you should check for are (pasting std fedora settings from my workstation):

  PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999

  PASS_MIN_DAYS   0

  PASS_MIN_LEN    5

  PASS_WARN_AGE   7

Comment: It worked after adding `account     required      pam_unix.so`  to /etc/pam.d/cs-auth